# Java how to count how many times if statement returned true

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            //Statement
            int count = 0;
            if (ResultABinary.equals(ResultBBinary)) {
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);
            }
            // System.out.println(count);
        }
```

In this code i am getting count 1 1 1, if i print out commented count i get 997 times 0, how do i do that my println would be 3? in short i want to count how many time if statement returned true and printout that number

Comment: Move `int count = 0` before the `for` loop

Comment: that last line is printed for each iteration of your loop, and that is indeed almost 1K times

Comment: Presumably the answer is either 1000 or 0: you're not (obviously) changing `ResultABinary` or `ResultBBinary` in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count = 0;    
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    //Statement
    if (ResultABinary.equals(ResultBBinary)) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    //Statement
    if (ResultABinary.equals(ResultBBinary)) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }

}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Why did you declare `count` as `static`?

Comment: Actually i was writing API for my large Java EE application so in that flow i declared that variable as static. :)